# Place cursor at the end of edit text with actionNext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have many `EditText`s on screen. I use

```
    <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
```

for focus on next edit text. But cursor always place at first position. Is there way to focus on next `EditText` and place cursor at the end of input? I know how to do it programmaticaly, but i want to set it in xml